# disable Spring Security if user logins using a social network (Google)

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-social

I have a Spring boot-angularjs. I have secured the the application using **Spring Security**. The problem I am facing now is , The home page (/home.html)  is secured so the user has to login before he can see the home page. Now I want to add **Google Plus Login** to my application and I can't figure out how as the *home page is secured and even if the user login's using google he/she cant access the home page as I am using jdbc authentication (username,password)*. Can anyone please tell how I can solve this?

Comment: i assume you use some base login page for user/pass auth, can you update that page for select type of auth?

Answer (score 1):

You can use OAuth in combination with your JDBC login. If the user chooses to login using Google he will be redirected to Google Login page. This is absolutely possible.

Examples: https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-boot-oauth2
       https://github.com/Baeldung/spring-security-oauth

Comment: well I cant get the password to store inside jdbc

Comment: @Jois you do not need to store the password, you get a token from Google that you use,  this is the goal of OAuth. I advise you to checkout the examples in the links, and try to run them.

Comment: I mean you are talking about the token we get when the user first signup's for the app?

Comment: So you want me to store the token and authenticate using it?

Comment: You do not need to store the token, every time the user needs to login, he will have two options: either jdbc which is what you store, or Google +. If the user chooses G+ then he will be redirected to G+ login page in which he will enter his credentials securely, once he authenticates, the approval (token ) is sent to Spring Security which opens a session and authenticates the user. It's not that complex to set up.

Comment: ok Thanks can I do this using angular js?? I am using angular js for the outh (not using any spring social) what can I do to authorize now?

Comment: Yes off course. You do need not spring social, only Spring OAuth, and you need to create a project in google developers console, to obtain a client id, and a client secret.